# "Read more" links and W3C's suggestions

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation, article

On my list of articles, I am linking via the heading and also via a "Read more" link:

```
<article>
  <h3><a href="#">Title here</a></h3>
  <p class="lead">Lead here</p>
  <a href="#" title="Title here">Read more</a>
</article>
```

Having read [W3C's tips on avoiding verbs in link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere), I was reluctant to have a "Read more" link, but I feel it is necessary to advise the user there is more to read as they reach the end of the lead text.

Is the use of `title="Title here"` a good compromise?

Comment: *Read more about* `<a>(...)</a>`

Comment: Titles can be up to 80 characters long and the "Read more" link is a button.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I went with a `span` tag that is only visible to screen readers:

```
<a href="#">Read more<span class="sr-only"> about 'Title here'</span></a>
```

Some sites embed screen reader text in the article itself to ensure their work is credited when copied and pasted to another site:

```
<p>Paragraph one here.</p>
<p class="sr-only">Read more at <a href="#">our-site.com</a></p>
<p>Paragraph 2 here.</p>
```

It's a healthy compromise, since hopefully pleases search engines and certainly pleases screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

(Personally, I don’t agree with the tip *never* to use verb phrases.)

In my opinion, "Read more" is problematic because it isn’t useful/meaningful out of context. Think of a typical blog front page, listing 10 recent article snippets. If screen reader users use the function to show all links on the page, they get something like:

> Hyperlink: Read more
>   Hyperlink: Read more
>   Hyperlink: Read more
>   Hyperlink: Read more
>   …

So they have no idea where these links will lead to. (… read more of *what*?)

So you should include this context in the link, i.e., the article title.

In principle, using the `title` attribute would be appropriate. However, many user agents (including many screen readers) ignore this attribute by default. So to be on the safe side, the article title should be included in the anchor text instead. (If you want, you could visually hide it, so that it still gets read to screen reader users.)

You may also consider to omit this link altogether (if you visually make clear that the headline is a link, and if you only show a short summary/introduction that can’t possibly be assumed to be the full article). Some related discussions on UX SE:

- [Use of 'read more' on teaser copy on index pages - is it necessary?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/13346/17023)
- [Should I have “read more” links in a responsive design?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/49824/17023)

---

In any case, you might want to use the [`bookmark` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#link-type-bookmark) for the link to the full article.

```
<article>
  <h3><a href="#" rel="bookmark">Title here</a></h3>
  <!-- … -->
</article>
```